# Não consigo usar o foreach com objeto duas vezes na mesma view no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Estou com um grande problema que não consigo resolver pois ainda sou iniciante em Laravel. O problema é que estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e preciso listar o objeto cidades em dois select diferentes, porém quando adiciono o segundo foreach dá um erro dizendo que não possível encontrar o objeto mas quando apago este foreach e deixo apenas um a aplicação funciona normalmente.
Segue a parte do código onde preciso fazer as duas listagens:

```
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <img src="/img/banner.png" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                {!! Form::open(['url'=>'index/oportunidades']) !!}
                <div class="col-md-12">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('cidades', 'Selecione uma Cidade:') !!}
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="cidade">
                                @foreach($cidades as $cidades)
                                    <option value="{{$cidades->id}}">{{ $cidades->nome }} - {{ $cidades->estado->sigla }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('categorias', 'Selecione uma Categoria:') !!}
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="categoria">
                               @foreach($categorias as $categorias)
                                    <option value="{{$categorias->id}}">{{$categorias->nome}}</option>
                               @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Filtrar</button>
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Empresas -->
<div id="ModalEmpresas" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <img src="/img/banner.png" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                {!! Form::open(['url'=>'index/oportunidades']) !!}
                <div class="col-md-12">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('cidades', 'Selecione uma Cidade:') !!}
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="cidade">
                                @foreach($cidades as $cidades)
                                    <option value="{{$cidades->id}}">{{ $cidades->nome }} - {{ $cidades->estado->sigla }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('categorias', 'Selecione uma Categoria:') !!}
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="categoria">
                               @foreach($categorias as $categorias)
                                    <option value="{{$categorias->id}}">{{$categorias->nome}}</option>
                               @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Filtrar</button>
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

E abaixo o código do controller:

```
public function index(){
    $cidades = cidades::all();
    $categorias = categorias::all();
    $oportunidades = oportunidades::all();
    return view('index', compact('cidades', 'categorias', 'oportunidades'));
}
```

Comment: No seu exemplo não tem os dois foreach de cidade que você citou.
Você pode postar o erro também?

Comment: Tem cara! confere de novo. Um está no primeiro modal e o segundo está no segundo modal. Assim como os foreach da categoria que também dá erro na hora de executar a aplicação.

Comment: Esse é o erro que dá: "Trying to get property of non-object".

Answer (score 3):

O **erro**:

```
@foreach($cidades as $cidades)
    <option value="{{$cidades->id}}">
          {{ $cidades->nome }} - {{ $cidades->estado->sigla }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

Explicação: no `foreach` na coleção de cidades sendo passada para a mesma variável, não pode esta sobrescrevendo é um erro de conceito, mudo o nome da variável:

**Correto**:

```
@foreach($cidades as $c)
    <option value="{{$c->id}}">
          {{ $c->nome }} - {{ $c->estado->sigla }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

O mesmo caso acontece em Categorias, arrume o nome da variável, não pode ser o mesmo nome da coleção.

Um outra otimização é no seu `controller` no `model` **cidades** force o carregamento de **estado**, isso melhora o desempenho porque gera em 2 `SQL` o que precisa, já o outro a cada interação é feito um consulta no banco (baixo desempenho):

```
public function index()
{
    $cidades = cidades::with('estado')->get();  
    $categorias = categorias::all();
    $oportunidades = oportunidades::all();
    return view('index', compact('cidades', 'categorias', 'oportunidades'));
}
```

Comment: Cara eu fiz o que você falou porém o erro ainda continua.

Comment: @Daislan qual é o erro? Poste na sua pergunta os 3 models cidades, categorias e oportunidades e coloque também qual é ou são as linhas do problema

Comment: É o mesmo erro da pergunta. Continua a dizer que  "Trying to get property of non-object".

Comment: Em qual linha @Daislan e coloque no seu model o que eu pedi, se não é impossivel pegar o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui enfim resolver o problema! É porque no primeiro foreach eu atribuia a variavel $cidades ao meu objeto $cidades então no segundo foreach ele pegava a variavel $cidades e não objeto $cidades. Ou seja, era apenas um erro de repetição de variavel.